# Check if encrypted USB has been accessed

Tags: usb, security, download

I mislaid my encrypted USB memory stick for a while (I now have the memory stick in my possession) and I am concerned that someone may have known my password and accessed and saved files to another computer. Is there a way to 
1) see if and when the USB was plugged into another computer.
2) see who's computer it was.
3) see what files, if any, were accessed and downloaded to the other computer.

Comment: This sort of logging would have only existed, if it exists,on the system the device was mounted on.  This information would NOT exist on the device itself.  Since you don't have access to that system the logs cannot be accessed.

Comment: Short answer: 1) No. 2) No. 3) No. Long answer: Somebody could have taken a disk image of your USB and be examining it at their leisure.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I recently did that in order to archive my work documents,came in handy when work needed those documents a few months later, after I had turned in the HDD after i left the organization.  The backup was an encrypted image of a bitlocker device, which means, I have to input 2 different passwords in order to access the data.

Comment: In XP it had a last accessed properties feature. depending on that OS was used to access the usb if it recorded the last accessed property in file properties. last accessed was disabled on Vista and above Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But why do you care if it has been properly encrypted?
If you don't trust your encryption, you have a different issue to solve.